# Pandas. ¿Cómo eliminar las columnas en un data frame que no están en otro data frame?

Tags: python, pandas

Tengo un data_frame_1 con 591 columnas y otro data_frame_2 con 222. Lo que quiero es tener el data_frame_1 pero solo con las columnas cuyo nombre están en el data_frame_2.

Por ejemplo en el data_frame_1 podria tener las columnas:

```
Barcelona | Buenos Aires | New York | Sao Pablo | Toronto
```

Y en el data_frame_2 podria tener las columnas:

```
Barcelona | Buenos Aires | Sao Pablo
```

Quiero tener el data_frame_1 (con los datos de este) pero solo con las columnas que coinciden con el data_frame_2:
Barcelona | Buenos Aires | Sao Pablo

Answer (score 1):

En primer lugar creo dos `DataFrame` de ejemplo:

```
import pandas
import numpy

numpy.random.seed(42)
df1 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.random((10,5)), columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4', 'c5'])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.random((10,3)), columns=['c3', 'c5', 'c6'])
```

Vemos que `df1` tiene 5 columnas, el nombre es arbitrario, en tu caso serán otros.

```
         c1        c2        c3        c4        c5
0  0.374540  0.950714  0.731994  0.598658  0.156019
1  0.155995  0.058084  0.866176  0.601115  0.708073
2  0.020584  0.969910  0.832443  0.212339  0.181825
3  0.183405  0.304242  0.524756  0.431945  0.291229
4  0.611853  0.139494  0.292145  0.366362  0.456070
5  0.785176  0.199674  0.514234  0.592415  0.046450
6  0.607545  0.170524  0.065052  0.948886  0.965632
7  0.808397  0.304614  0.097672  0.684233  0.440152
8  0.122038  0.495177  0.034389  0.909320  0.258780
9  0.662522  0.311711  0.520068  0.546710  0.184854
```

Por otro lado `df2`tendrá algunas columnas coincidentes y otras no

```
         c3        c5        c6
0  0.969585  0.775133  0.939499
1  0.894827  0.597900  0.921874
2  0.088493  0.195983  0.045227
3  0.325330  0.388677  0.271349
4  0.828738  0.356753  0.280935
5  0.542696  0.140924  0.802197
6  0.074551  0.986887  0.772245
7  0.198716  0.005522  0.815461
8  0.706857  0.729007  0.771270
9  0.074045  0.358466  0.115869
```

Es claro que lo que queremos es solo mostrar las columnas `c3` y `c5` de `df1`, para esto, podemos hacer:

```
seleccion = [c for c in df1.columns.tolist() if c in df2.columns.tolist()]
df1[seleccion]
```

Resultado:

```
         c3        c5
0  0.731994  0.156019
1  0.866176  0.708073
2  0.832443  0.181825
3  0.524756  0.291229
4  0.292145  0.456070
5  0.514234  0.046450
6  0.065052  0.965632
7  0.097672  0.440152
8  0.034389  0.258780
9  0.520068  0.184854
```